# How to make dynamic combobox in ExtJS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a combobox include true, false and all stuation on ExtJS. If I choose true on combobox send 1 to API and I choose false on combobox send 2,3 etc. to API. My code run static like below :

```
try {
    var comboStoreConfig = X.store.comboStoreConfig();
    comboStoreConfig.displayField = "name";
    comboStoreConfig.valueField = "id";
    comboStoreConfig.useDbData = false;
    comboStoreConfig.staticData = [];
    comboStoreConfig.initialValue = config.initialValue;

    comboStoreConfig.staticData.push({"id": 1, "ad":"True"});
    comboStoreConfig.staticData.push({"id": 2, "ad":"False"});
    comboStoreConfig.staticData.push({"id": 0, "ad":"All"});

    return X.store.createStoreToCombo(config, comboStoreConfig);
} catch (e) {
 //throw exception
}
```

How can I make dynamic combobox ? For example when I choose "false" on combobox the id must go to API like 2,3 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combobox has two config `valueField` and `displayField`, using these configs we can have a text that display on the picker list `(displayField)` and value can be different using `valueField`

Refer docs for more info
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html

```
// The data store containing the list of states
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['display', 'value'],
    data : [
        {"display":"True", "value":"1"},
        {"display":"False", "value":"2"}
    ]
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'display',
    valueField: 'value'
});
```